# Iced Tea plugin keeps asking for permission to run Java applets

Tags: 14.04, java, icedtea

Every time the browser wants to load a Java applet a dialog asking me for permission to run the java applet appears. No matter if I check the option "remember this option" or not, the dialog appears, annoyingly, every time the browser tries to show a Java applet.

Here there's a picture showing the phenomenon.

[image]

Is there any solution to this annoying permission dialog?

Thanks in advance,

Charlie

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 29.0 that came along with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I do not have such a slider under the security tab. Is there a way to whitelist some IP's or a range of addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Because of the high number of virus using vulnerabilities of the Java language, Firefox, by default, ask every time if we want to open a Java applet, whatever the system policy.

However, it is possible to change it.

Open the Add-on manager (ctrl+Shift+A) and select the "plugin" tab. Change the combobox next to "IcedTead-Web Plugin" to "Always activate" (Sorry if the name are not accurate, i'm French)

Comment: I thought it was going to work, but no luck :(

Comment: Have you tried to purge and reinstall icedtea plugin?

Comment: I did it, but no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

I get exactly the same thing. I believe this is a new java security feature - it happens on all OS's I believe (OSX, Linux and Windows). As far as I can tell, there is no obvious solution, however you could try the following:

1. Open Dash (super).
2. Search "java".
3. Click on "Oracle Java 7 Plugin Control Panel".

   - You may need to install it from the software centre.
4. Click on the Security tab.
5. Change the slider to Medium.

This may solve the problem.

Comment: Is dash a shell? That's the only dash I know

Comment: No, the Dash/Launcher. Press Super, it should open a window with recent files and applications etc. You can search from there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have KDE. If I install Oracle Java 7, should I uninstall the icedtea plugin?

Comment: Yes, do remove icedtea if you get oracle.